# DecimalPipe in angular cut the string if its more than 10 digits

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I use decimal pipe to format the number in input field

`value| number:'0.0-6': 'en-us'`

When I use number with more than 10 digits shows this:

on `11111111111.123456` returns `11,111,111,111.123455`

on `111111111111.123456` returns `111,111,111,111.12345`

on `1111111111111.123456` returns `1,111,111,111,111.1234`

on `11111111111111.123456` returns `11,111,111,111,111.123`

It does not matter width of the input field.

Does anyone had the same issue? Is there any workaround?

I also try with `11999999999999.999999` and it shows `12,000,000,000,000`

Answer (score 0):

[DecimalPipe can render maximum 22 chars](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/i18n/format_number.ts). This value was hardcoded and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom pipe with your custom logic.